# White Space on mobile version

Tags: html, css

I have a problem thats bugging me.

http://i40.tinypic.com/69n66t.png
It seems its just keeping the original size of everything, I want it to just zoom out to fit everything on the screen automatically.

I'm learning to try and become a web developer / desiginer. I havn't had this issue before on my own mobile. I can zoom out but then the full width DIV with a slider in the center. Everything cuts off to the right theres like 100px of white space, and everything that i've aligned to the middle is all to the right.

Anyone have any ideas? this is probbaly an easy fix.

CSS for the full width DIV

```
#slider {
    margin:0px auto 20px auto;
    height:350px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: visible;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(images/content.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;

    }
```

Comment: add `min-width: 100%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may just be a problem with the tinypic service you are using...

Also, you might want to consider using responsive design with a css media tag like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    #slider{
        /* Any changes you want to happen here */
    }
}
```

Don't be intimidated either... Web design is very tricky, and takes a lot to get right. I was you about two months ago. Just keep trying! Hope this helps, if not, let me know!

Comment: I think this worked! i changed the 100% to 720px on that query.
also changed the repeat-x to background-size:cover; and added <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0"/>

Thankyou for your help!

Comment: Any time! Hope you do well in web design!